# R monthly report - pageview data - duplicate pages but different pageviews. Is there a way to combine?

Tags: r, google-analytics

I'm trying to create a monthly report of some web metric data and sadly the stakeholder wants to see every single URL. This would usually be fine, but they forgot to exclude some of the tracking parameters in Google Analytics so lots of URLs are duplicated with parameters like fbclid. An example of what it looks like, except in reality I have about 900 URLs:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~month, ~url, ~pageviews, ~bouncerate,
  "04", "services-we-provide", 800, 30,
  "04", "services-we-provide?fbclid=iwar1m1xyneodn1z3inhbdbe", 5, 20,
  "04", "services-we-provide?fbclid=idwiw1xyneodn1z3inhbdbe", 1, 1,
  "04", "services-we-provide?fbclid=iwar1m1xyneodn1zrewerwe", 40, 30
)

  month url                                                 pageviews bouncerate
  <chr> <chr>                                                   <dbl>      <dbl>
1 04    services-we-provide                                       800         30
2 04    services-we-provide?fbclid=iwar1m1xyneodn1z3inhbdbe         5         20
3 04    services-we-provide?fbclid=idwiw1xyneodn1z3inhbdbe          1          1
4 04    services-we-provide?fbclid=iwar1m1xyneodn1zrewerwe         40         30
```

I've removed the fbclid bit using `mutate(pagePath = str_replace(pagePath, "\\?fbclid.*", ""))` but then I have many rows that have the same value in the `url` column but separate values in the `pageviews` and `bouncerate` column. In the below example, how could I combine row 2, 3, 4 into row1 preserving the value in `month` but summing the values in `pageviews` (and preferable average in `bouncerate`). Should also note I still need the url column to exist. So it would simply turn into:

```
  month url                                                 pageviews bouncerate
  <chr> <chr>                                                   <dbl>      <dbl>
1 04    services-we-provide                                       846         30
```

All this is going to be appended into a Google Sheet so I think I can simply use a pivot table that automatically removes the duplicates for me but would still like to know how to do it in R or the sheet will get messy very quickly!

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your on the right track, I'd suggest you have a look at [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) as it offers a very simple and powerful data-manipulation semantic.

In your case, you can do everything in one-go:

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(url = str_replace(url, "\\?fbclid.*", "")) %>%   # remove tags
  group_by(month, url) %>% 
  summarise(pageviews = sum(pageviews),
            bouncerate = mean(bouncerate))

# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   month [1]
#  month url                 pageviews bouncerate
#  <chr> <chr>                   <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 04    services-we-provide       846       20.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do that with `aggregate`.

```
df <- transform(df, url=gsub("\\?fbclid.*", "", url))

df <- aggregate(cbind(pageviews, bouncerate) ~ url, df, function(x) 
  c(sum=sum(x), mean=mean(x)))
df
#                   url pageviews.sum pageviews.mean bouncerate.sum bouncerate.mean
# 1 services-we-provide         846.0          211.5          81.00           20.25
```

**Or** you also may want to try `ave`, since it might be helpful when the data dimensions should not change.

```
df <- within(df, {
  url <- gsub("\\?fbclid.*", "", url)
  pageviews <- ave(pageviews, url, FUN=sum)
  bouncerate <- ave(bouncerate, url, FUN=mean)
})
```

Of course here we may want to delete the duplicates.

```
df <- df[!duplicated(df),]
#   month                 url pageviews bouncerate
# 1    04 services-we-provide       846      20.25
```

Comment: thank you! Both your answers helped me and I didn't know about `ave` so that's great to know. I accepted anddt's answer simply because I think dplyr will be easier to understand for others that run into a similar issue in the future. Thanks

Comment: @duncan See update `aggregate`. Personally I don't think that installing/learning a completely new package is easier to understand than a single new command that already comes with R.